# How to get a pagination route to load properly in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-router

I have a route at `#/posts` for posts that shows the first page of posts, and a pagination route at `#/posts/:page_id` that shows whatever page you request. My router looks like this:

```
App.Router.map(function(match) {
  //...
  this.route('posts');
  this.resource('postsPage', { path: '/posts/:page_id' });
});
```

And those routes look like this:

```
App.PostsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.store.find(App.Post, { 'page': params.page_id });
  }
});

App.PostsPageRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('posts');
  },
  model: function(params) {
    return App.store.find(App.Post, { 'page': params.page_id });
  }
});
```

This worked fine for about a month after I implemented it, but it recently stopped working for anything but the `#/posts` route. Pages don't load, even though my REST API returns the right JSON.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/davissorenson/tkPxX/)
`#/posts` route [here](http://jsfiddle.net/davissorenson/tkPxX/show/#/posts)
`#/posts/1` route [here](http://jsfiddle.net/davissorenson/tkPxX/show/#/posts/1) (note it doesn't load the content even though the JSON is sent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the postsPageRoute will setup the postsPage controller.  You need to tell it to setup the posts controller.

```
App.PostsPageRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this.controllerFor('posts').set('content', model)
  },
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('posts');
  },
  model: function(params) {
    return App.store.find(App.Post, { 'page': params.page_id });
  }
});
```